# VisualStudio 2017: Syntax error missing ':' before '^'

Tags: winforms, visual-studio-2017, c++-cli

I have the following:

FileReader.cpp

```
#include "FileReader.h"
#include "FileData.h"

using namespace System;
using namespace System::IO;


FileReader::FileReader(){}

System::Void FileReader::readFile(System::String^ fileName) {
    this->_fileName = fileName;
    Console::WriteLine("Opening: " + _fileName);

    try {
        StreamReader^ fileIn = File::OpenText(_fileName);

        System::String^ input;
        int count = 0;
        while ((count < 10 && (input = fileIn->ReadLine()) != nullptr)) {
            Console::WriteLine(input);
            count++;
        }

    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException^ e) {
        Console::WriteLine("FileNotFound");
    }
}
```

FileReader.h

```
#pragma once

ref class FileReader
{
public:
    FileReader();

    FileData^ fData = gcnew FileData(); // This is whats causing the errors.
    System::String^ _fileName;
    System::Void readFile(System::String^ fileName);
};
```

FileData.cpp

```
#include "FileData.h"

FileData::FileData(){}

System::Void FileData::Set_DataName(System::String^ dName)
{
    this->dataName= dName;
}
```

FileData.h

```
#pragma once
using namespace System;

ref class FileData
{
public:
    FileData();

    System::String^ dataName;
    System::Void Set_PlayerName(System::String^ dName);

};
```

Problem I'm having is the compiler returns big list of errors when trying to create the FileData object in FileReader.h

```
Error   C2143   syntax error: missing ';' before '^'
Error   C4430   missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int    
Error   C2238   unexpected token(s) preceding ';'
Error   C2143   syntax error: missing ';' before '^'
Error   C4430   missing type specifier - int assumed.
Error   C2238   unexpected token(s) preceding ';'
Error   C2143   syntax error: missing ';' before '^'    
Error   C4430   missing type specifier - int assumed. 
Error   C2238   unexpected token(s) preceding ';'
```

I know its probably something simple I've missed but I can't figure out what I've done wrong. Anyone able to help?

Comment: This is not C++, but some dialect like C++/CLI. Please retag accordingly.

Comment: "FileReader.h" should include "FileData.h" since the `FileReader` class has a `FileData` pointer.

Comment: I tried that, it will return a large number of different errors, all the same: Error (active) E0266 "IServiceProvider" is ambiguous

Comment: As @JohnnyMopp points out you're working on the wrong errors.  As things stand `FileData` is an unknown type within `FileReader.h` so the line that starts `FileData^ fData = gcnew …` will give you the C4430 error because the type `FileData` is unspecified.  Once you fix that you can start working on the other errors you get - perhaps with a new question in StackOverflow.